# How to refactor code with a lot of constructor-instantiated classes and deep hierarchy?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, refactoring

I have some code that I would like to refactor.  It looks like this:

```
class Calc
{
    function __construct($product = null)
    {
        // original code
        $this->spec = new Spec();
        $this->price = new Price();
        $this->motor = new Motor();
        $this->drive = new Drive();
        $this->turbine = new Turbine();
        $this->pump = new Pump();

        // new code:
        if ($product == "S")
            $this->option = new OptionsS();
        else
            $this->option = new Options();
    }
}
```

What I am thinking of doing is passing individual classes to Calc using DI via constructor.  Namely, since all of the `new` classes are required I am considering something like this:

```
$array = array(
    'spec' => new Spec(),
    'price' = new Price(),
    ...
    'option' = (new OptionFactory($product))->returnOption()),
);

$calc = new (Calc($array));


//then
class Calc
{
    function __construct($array)
    {
        // original code
        $this->spec = $array['spec'];
        $this->price = $array['price'];
         ...
        $this->option = $array['option'];
    }
}
```

I am thinking that will work.  The caveat is that there is another class that needs `Calc`. Namely:

```
class ProductA extends Product
{
    function __construct() {
        $this->calc        = new Calc();
        $this->tech        = new Tech();
        $this->plot        = new Plot();
        $this->outline    = new Outline();
        ...
        $this->input    = new Input();
    }
}
```

which will put me with DI upon DI pattern.  Do I just apply DI recursively until everything is constructor-DIed?  Is there a better way?  Do I just leave the code alone?

**Question:**  How to deal with code that has a lot of child classes and deep hierarchy (say a tree of classes 3-4 deep and each class has about 4-5 classes instantiated inside the constructor).  My initial thought is to use DI, to "simplify it" but looking at all the work involved in refactoring for DI, and seeing how we have DI upon DI, I am not sure if will be worth it.

I am looking for better ways to refactor such code.